# Can you create a read only encrypted partition that root cannot write to (or remount)?

Tags: root, encryption, devices

I have an encrypted partition that I would like to be mounted as read only. The catch is that I do not want a root user to be able to remount the partition as read-write unless they have the encryption key. I know that root can generally do everything (including recreating the encryption key from a memory dump), but cryptsetup has a --readonly option

```
--readonly, -r
          set up a read-only mapping.
```

How does the readonly option work? Does it create a device /dev/mapper/foo such that foo can only be mounted read only? Would this prevent root from remapping the device as read-write (assuming root does not have the encryption key). If not, is there a way to accomplish this?

I know there is no way to stop root from either extracting the encryption key from memory or from copying the read only data to a temporary location, reformatting the encrypted device and copying the read only data back to the device as read-write. What I am trying to prevent are things like `mount -o rw /dev/mapper/foo /mnt`.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to keep root from getting write access, if root has read. Root has write access to the underlying block device, after all; it could sidestep any software measures by sniffing the key out of memory and computing its own (encrypted) writes.

Comment: However, there's some interesting work with limiting root accounts via SELinux or other MAC systems. It's possible something along those lines could work; however, I think it would have to be very custom and not easy to set up.

Comment: @TomHunt I know root can sniff the key out and I know root can destroy the underlying block device.

Comment: The issue isn't just that it can destroy it. The issue is that, if it knows the key, it can compute the same encrypted writes that `dm-crypt` would make in read-write mode, and make them itself. Thus, there's no read-only mode available; it would be pointless.

Comment: One way to work around this problem would be to mount the partition over NFS. The NFS server dictates how it can be used (ro,root_squash) but root on the NFS server would still have full access to the partition.